# Modify .fill_short_gaps function in zoo library

Tags: r, zoo

I'd like to modify the effects of the maxgaps argument of the .fill_short_gaps function in the R zoo library (used in na.locf and na.approx), as described in uday's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20709929/r-no-documentation-for-fill-short-gaps#comment31022823_20710066).

The following example illustrates existing behavior in the context of na.locf.

```
x <- c(rep(NA, 2), 1:4, rep(NA, 4), 7:8, rep(NA, 2), 9:10)
y <- na.locf(x, na.rm=FALSE, maxgap=2)
rbind(x, y)
```

Which results in

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]

x    NA   NA    1    2    3    4   NA   NA   NA    NA     7     8    NA    NA     9    10

y    NA   NA    1    2    3    4   NA   NA   NA    NA     7     8     8     8     9    10
```

However, I'd like the group of four internal NAs in 7:10 to be filled forward with `maxgap` values, with the rest as NAs.  E.g.:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16]
x   NA   NA    1    2    3    4   NA   NA   NA    NA     7     8    NA    NA     9    10
z   NA   NA    1    2    3    4    4    4   NA    NA     7     8     8     8     9    10
```

For reference, here is the [.fill_short_gaps function](http://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/zoo/R/na.approx.R?view=markup&root=zoo) from the zoo package:

```
## x = series with gaps
## fill = same series with filled gaps
.fill_short_gaps <- function(x, fill, maxgap) {
    if (maxgap <= 0)
        return(x)
    if (maxgap >= length(x))
        return(fill)
    naruns <- rle(is.na(x))

    # This is the part I want to modify.  Currently sets all runs > maxgap
    # to FALSE (meaning don't fill)
    naruns$values[naruns$lengths > maxgap] <- FALSE

    naok <- inverse.rle(naruns)
    ifelse(naok, fill, x)
}
```

Using `x` as the example, `naruns` looks like this:

```
naruns

Run Length Encoding
    lengths: int [1:6] 2 4 4 2 2 2
    values : logi [1:6] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

One approach to solving my problem would involve inserting values in the appropriate places in the `naruns` vectors so that `naok` can be created correctly.  This would look like:

```
Run Length Encoding
    lengths: int [1:7] 2 4 2 2 2 2 2
    values : logi [1:7] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

That is, the 4 (TRUE) in position 3 would be split into 2 (TRUE) and 2 (FALSE), that is, at positions identified by `which(naruns$values & naruns$lengths > maxgap)` but I'm not sure of a good way to insert values in the correct positions.

I've considered several clumsy approaches to doing this, but they've ended in dead ends.  I know from looking at the answers to other (unrelated) questions on SO that many can come up with something much more robust and scalable than anything I am likely to emit in a reasonable timespan.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was able to answer my own question, once I had identified the problem more narrowly.  They key problem in the approach I described above was to insert values into a vector at specified positions.  I found a good way to do that at [How to insert elements into a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493969/how-to-insert-elements-into-a-vector).  Using the accepted answer there, I created this function that fills runs of NAs up to a specified maximum number and leaves the rest as NAs.

It's based on zoo::na.locf except that I replaced the .fill_short_gaps with the version shown below:

```
fillNa <- function (object, na.rm = TRUE, fromLast, rev, maxfill = Inf, 
                    rule = 2, ...) {

    ## x = series with gaps
    ## fill = same series with filled gaps
    .fill_short_gaps <- function(x, fill, maxfill) {
        if (maxfill <= 0)
            return(x)
        if (maxfill >= length(x))
            return(fill)

        naruns <- rle(is.na(x))
        len <- length(naruns$lengths)

        # Identify which runs are greater than maxfill
        fill.idx <- which(naruns$values & naruns$lengths > maxfill)

        # Create a new naruns
        naruns2 <- vector('list', 2)
        attr(naruns2, 'class') <- 'rle'

        idx <- c(seq_along(naruns$values), fill.idx + 0.5)
        naruns2$values <- c(naruns$values, rep(FALSE, length(fill.idx)))
        naruns2$values[fill.idx] <- TRUE
        naruns2$values <- naruns2$values[order(idx)]

        fill.lngth <- naruns$lengths[fill.idx]
        naruns2$lengths <- c(naruns$lengths, (fill.lngth - maxfill))
        naruns2$lengths[fill.idx] <- maxfill
        naruns2$lengths <- naruns2$lengths[order(idx)]

        naok <- rep(NA, length(x))

        naok <- inverse.rle(naruns2)
        ifelse(naok, fill, x)
    }

    L <- list(...)
    if ("x" %in% names(L) || "xout" %in% names(L)) {
        if (!missing(fromLast)) {
            stop("fromLast not supported if x or xout is specified")
        }
        return(na.approx(object, na.rm = na.rm, maxfill = maxfill, 
                         method = "constant", rule = rule, ...))
    }
    na.locf.0 <- function(x) {
        L <- !is.na(x)
        idx <- if (fromLast) 
                   rev(c(NA, rev(which(L)))[cumsum(rev(L)) + 1])
               else c(NA, which(L))[cumsum(L) + 1]
        na.index <- function(x, i) {
            L <- !is.na(i)
            x[!L] <- NA
            x[L] <- coredata(x)[i[L]]
            x
        }
        xf <- na.index(x, idx)
        .fill_short_gaps(x, xf, maxfill = maxfill)
    }

    if (!missing(rev)) {
        warning("na.locf.default: rev= deprecated. Use fromLast= instead.")
        if (missing(fromLast)) 
            fromLast <- rev
    }
    else if (missing(fromLast)) 
        fromLast <- FALSE
    rev <- base::rev
    object[] <- if (length(dim(object)) == 0) 
                    na.locf.0(object)
                else apply(object, length(dim(object)), na.locf.0)
    if (na.rm) 
        na.trim(object, is.na = "all")
    else object
}
```